# Akka context become preserving state order

Tags: scala, akka, mutable

I have the following simple Actor:

```
class MutableStateActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var counter = 0

  val increment = (x: Int) => {
    counter = counter + 1
    s"$counter"
  }

  def receive = {
    case _ => context.become(mutableReceiver)
  }

  def mutableReceiver: Receive = {
    case Increment => {
      Future { println(s"counter in Increment is ${increment(counter)}"); self ! CounterStatus }
      //println(s"counter in Increment is ${increment(counter)}"); self ! CounterStatus
    }
    case CounterStatus => {
      println(counter)
    }
  }
}
object MutableStateActor {
  case class Increment()
  case class CounterStatus()
}
```

When I test it using the following test:

```
  "A MutableStateActor" must {

    val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props[MutableStateActor])

    "mutate state in order" in {
      1 to 5 foreach {
        x => actorRef ! Increment
      }
    }
  }
```

I can see that the order in which the counter gets incremented is preserved. I get:

```
counter in Increment is 1
counter in Increment is 2
counter in Increment is 3
counter in Increment is 4
4
4
4
4
```

If I change my receive method in my actor as below without doing a context.become:

```
 def receive: Receive = {
    case Increment => {
      Future { println(s"counter in Increment is ${increment(counter)}"); self ! CounterStatus }
      //println(s"counter in Increment is ${increment(counter)}"); self ! CounterStatus
    }
    case CounterStatus => {
      println(counter)
    }
  }
```

I get a non deterministic behavior with respect to the counter increment.

```
counter in Increment is 2
counter in Increment is 4
counter in Increment is 1
counter in Increment is 3
counter in Increment is 5
5
5
5
5
5
```

Comment: What is the effect of the context become? What does it do?

Comment: The `println` is being called in a `Future` in both cases, which means the ordering is non-deterministic in both cases. Just because you observe a specific behavior does not mean you can rely on the consistency of that behavior. The effect of context.become is irrelevant.
That being said, all you are seeing is probably the result of the delay caused by context.become

Comment: Yes, I ran it again a thousand times and I was able to notice the non-determinism using the context become!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 1st case, the `println`is executed when the `Future` is resolved, and they are resolved in the order they are created.

In the 2nd case, the `println` is executed in a thread, then return a `Future`, thus, the order of the thread execution is non-deterministic.

Comment: I did not understand that. In the second case as well, I'm returning a Future. All I want to know is what effect the context become has?